# In DevExpress TextEdit How to enter value with 3 decimal places and value should be max 1000

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I am using devexpress TextEditSettings in dxgrid in editsettings..

How can i restrict the user to enter value with 3 decimal places and value range should be 0-1000

Comment: You might want to try at http://community.devexpress.com/forums/ or http://documentation.devexpress.com/#HomePage/CustomDocument9453

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"

<Style x:Key="DXTextEdit_Numeric_Style" TargetType="{x:Type dxe:TextEdit}">
    <Setter Property="Mask" Value="000.000;000.000-" />
    <Setter Property="MaskType" Value="Numeric"/>
    <Setter Property="DisplayFormatString" Value="000.000;000.000-"/>
    <Setter Property="MaskUseAsDisplayFormat" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

**EDIT:**

Give this a try:

You will have to specify your column:

```
xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"

<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="SomeFieldName" Width="110" FilterPopupMode="CheckedList">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:TextEditSettings Style="{DynamicResource GridColumnStyle_Text}" />
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn>
```

Then your style:

```
<Style x:Key="GridColumnStyle_Numeric" TargetType="{x:Type dxe:TextEditSettings}">
    <Setter Property="Mask" Value="000.000;000.000-" />
    <Setter Property="MaskType" Value="Numeric"/>
    <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft"/>
    <Setter Property="DisplayFormatString" Value="000.000;000.000-"/>
    <Setter Property="MaskUseAsDisplayFormat" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: @tWillem: thanx i forgot to tell that i am using this in dxgrid edit mode.